# Django REST Browsable API Template Change

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I want to customize the Django REST Framework Browsable API template (simply to change the branding to a different name and link).

I have read the documentation on how to achieve this and did the following initially in the following path: hints(project)->hints1(app)->templates->rest_framework->api.html

api.html:

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}


{% block title %} Handy Dev Hints - API {% endblock %}

    {% block branding %}
    <span>
        <a class='navbar-brand' rel="nofollow" href="{% url 'html' %}">
             -----HTML View----- <span class="version">1</span>
         </a>
    </span>
    {% endblock %}
```

I also modified my settings.py as follows, specifically the DIRS section:

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

From the tutorials I've watched and the docs I read this should have been enough to implement the change. However, it did not work.

So then I decided to just change the base.html directly in the site-packages library.

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
.
. 
.
{% block body %}
  <body class="{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %}">

<div class="wrapper">
  {% block navbar %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top {% block bootstrap_navbar_variant %}navbar-inverse{% endblock %}"
         role="navigation" aria-label="{% trans "navbar" %}">
      <div class="container">
        <span>
          {% block branding %}
            <a class='navbar-brand' rel="nofollow" href="{% url 'html' %}">
              -----HTML View-----
            </a>
          {% endblock %}
```

This solution worked when I ran it on my local server. However, it did not work when I uploaded the files to an external server (I uploaded the `rest_framework` and `rest_framework_jwt` site-packages to the external server also, but I assume I'm still missing something).

Any advice on how to get the changes to work on the external server as suggested by the documentation? Or even via the base.html change method? (Or any other method).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There are a couple of things that could likely be the reason you are experiencing this problem:

1) **Firstly** you seem to have your api.htm file created in your app folder while you reference your templates folder at the level of the project directory meaning
[Your app template ref] ***Proj dir --> app --> templates --> api.html***
[django template lookup] ***Proj dir --> templates --> api.html*** which result to error

2) **Secondly** as alternative solution you chose to hack the site-package installation(very bad!! not recommend) while this would work locally, when you deploy your application on an external server, the DRF is reinstall in the external server (which this will not have any modifications you made)

## The **Recommended** course of action will be to either:

1) Move your ***api.htm*** to the project level folder .i.e. ***Proj dir --> templates --> api.html***

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}
   {% block title %} Handy Dev Hints - API {% endblock %}
     {% block branding %}
       <span>
        <a class='navbar-brand' rel="nofollow" href="{% url 'html' %}">
         -----HTML View----- <span class="version">1</span>
        </a>
       </span>
{% endblock %}
```

for django to easily find 
**OR**
2) Your add **os.path.join('BASE_DIR',*'YOUR_APP_DIR'*, 'templates')** to your template dir in the settings .i.e.

```
    TEMPLATES = [
{

    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'YOUR_APP_DIR', 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

## Update:

And if i may add, following the tutorial on how to customise this will work as long as everything is place within the appropriate path such that the framework can find, here is a screen short of a customisation I made.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for clarifying why the site-package hack didn't work! (it was a last resort).

Comment: Your are welcome @SteveKerr, hope you were able to customize your app. If you have need of help just let me know in case.

Comment: @Virtu_Acad, why you need to fill the DIRS attribute with the app templates path? isnt that what APP_DIRS =True for? It goes and looks for templates in the app/templates directory for every existing app

Comment: @MichaelR you need fill the DIRS because the templates in this path are often(but not limited to) those created by you, thus any modification will persist for the applications life-time even when deployed whereas APP_DIR search the template directory for installed app which will always be modified on deployment thereby overriding any changes you may make to it, hence reason why it is very bad and not recommended to hack it.